# R - hist3D of sequence colour and label issues

Tags: r, 3d, sequence, histogram

So I have a dataset with 5 rows and 20 columns. 
I am trying to plot a `hist3D` from the `plot3D` package.

```
dt = structure(c(1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 1, 1, 2, 1, 10, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 9, 0, 2, 4, 0, 4, 0, 5, 2, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 1, 3, 
2, 6, 8, 1, 2, 2, 4, 10, 0, 2, 2, 4, 7, 0, 7, 1, 4, 11, 0, 4, 
1, 2, 15, 0, 4, 2, 3, 16, 2, 7, 2, 2, 18, 3, 9, 0, 1, 15, 0, 
15, 0, 2), .Dim = c(5L, 20L), .Dimnames = list(c("f Housework", 
"g Odd jobs", "h Eating", "i Child care", "j Care for others"
), c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", 
"V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18", "V19", 
"V20")))
```

The histogram

```
hist3D(x = 1:5, z = dt, scale = T, col = jet.col(100, alpha = 0.3), add = F,  colkey = F, ticktype = "detailed")
```

[image: the figure]

What I would like is to

1. replace the `x-axis` (1:5) by the row.names (`"f Housework", 
   "g Odd jobs", "h Eating", "i Child care", "j Care for others"`
   )
2. Instead of having the same colours for each `x` variables, the rows of my data,  (1:5, `"f Housework", 
   "g Odd jobs", "h Eating", "i Child care", "j Care for others"`), 
   I would like to have for each rows a different colour (if possible a different "heat-map" sequence colours).

What I would like is something like this (manual draw I know) :

[image]

Any advice ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have a solution for the colors:
[image]

```
m <- matrix(rep(seq(5),each=20), ncol=20, nrow=5, byrow = TRUE)
hist3D(x = 1:5, z = dt, scale = T, col = jet.col(5, alpha = 0.3), add = F,  colvar = m, colkey = T, ticktype = "detailed")
```

I will update the post as soon as I find out how to modify the x-axis labels.

Comment: did you found out for the axis ?

Answer (score 5):

In case you haven't figured it out yet (or for the next person who comes along with a similar issue), there is a terrific blog post here about altering all axes things in hist3D: http://entrenchant.blogspot.co.uk/2014_03_01_archive.html