# Use R to draw a 4d figure

Tags: r, 4d

I have some data in CSV file and want to draw a 4d graphic. The x, y, z axis is respectively one column in the file. and the 4th dimension is a color respective of the value of another column in the file. How can I get a plot with both the x,y,z and color in R?

Comment: You might want to take a look at `demo(persp)` to see examples how this could be done in base R. The `hist3d()` function from the plot3D package could also be useful. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31247657/4770166) shows an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be able to make a 3D plot with color information encoded according to another variable in the data set. It depends on whether you need a surface or a scatterplot. For example, a 3D scatterplot package (`install.packages("scatterplot3d")` would result, using the `mtcars` dataset, in

```
library(scatterplot3d)
# create column indicating point color
mtcars$pcolor[mtcars$cyl==4] <- "red"
mtcars$pcolor[mtcars$cyl==6] <- "blue"
mtcars$pcolor[mtcars$cyl==8] <- "darkgreen"
with(mtcars, {
    s3d <- scatterplot3d(disp, wt, mpg,        # x y and z axis
                  color=pcolor, pch=19,        # circle color indicates no. of cylinders
                  type="h", lty.hplot=2,       # lines to the horizontal plane
                  scale.y=.75,                 # scale y axis (reduce by 25%)
                  main="3-D Scatterplot Example 4",
                  xlab="Displacement (cu. in.)",
                  ylab="Weight (lb/1000)",
                  zlab="Miles/(US) Gallon")
     s3d.coords <- s3d$xyz.convert(disp, wt, mpg)
     text(s3d.coords$x, s3d.coords$y,     # x and y coordinates
          labels=row.names(mtcars),       # text to plot
          pos=4, cex=.5)                  # shrink text 50% and place to right of points)
# add the legend
legend("topleft", inset=.05,      # location and inset
    bty="n", cex=.5,              # suppress legend box, shrink text 50%
    title="Number of Cylinders",
    c("4", "6", "8"), fill=c("red", "blue", "darkgreen"))
})
```

yielding

[image: 3d scatterplot with color information]

You can find a list of examples, including the one above, [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/?s=3d+plot).

Comment: The answer is very helpful. Thank you very much, Shawn. :)